# Cannot call AsyncTask doInBackground() and onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Strangley, my `AsyncTask` will execute `onPreExecute` but not `doInBackground()` or `onPostExecute()`.
Logcat has no error or message indicating that something is going wrong.

```
class LocationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute============");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground============");
        Log.d(TAG, "urls[0]:" + urls[0]);
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute============");
    }
}

public class CsLocationTaskTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    public void testExecute(){
        LocationTask task = new LocationTask();
        task.execute("my_test_url", null);
    }
}
```

As you see, `AsycTask` is nothing special, but `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` are not being called in both a test case and in my `Activity`. I don't understand what happened, please let me understand what is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will search more and try different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AsyncTask` needs to be a sub class of `CsLocationTaskTest`. Also, you don't need `null`.

Per the development document:

`"AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used. The subclass will override at least one method (doInBackground(Params...)), and most often will override a second one (onPostExecute(Result).)"`

Found at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Try this:

```
 public class CsLocationTaskTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    public void testExecute(){
        LocationTask task = new LocationTask();
        task.execute("my_test_url");
    }

    class LocationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute============");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground============");
        Log.d(TAG, "urls[0]:" + urls[0]);
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute============");
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Sorry, man. Your code does not work as I want. It is still same. AsyncTask should be tested in Thread. I solve this problem using InstrumentationTestCase class and runTestOnUiThread method.

Comment: That may be, but you still need to subclass `AsyncTask` if you keep it the way you had it, it will never work. Just make sure when you use it to build an app, you subclass `AsyncTask`.